# How to have Cyclic Generics inherited?

Tags: java, generics

I am creating a small framework for a board game platform and I have created the following interfaces in order to be as generic as possible for the games that I will be putting within this framework.

I wanted to use Java Generics, so that each implementation would then not only 
implement the respective interfaces in a proper OO way, but also have the specific concrete class for the game-specific requirements accessible and strongly typed (without casts etc.).

For example, a `CheckersPlayer` would extend `Player` (and `CheckersPlayerImpl` implements `CheckersPlayer`), `CheckersGame` would extend `Game` (with `CheckersGameImpl` implementing `CheckersGame`) and `CheckersGameTable` extending `GameTable` etc.

```
public interface Player
{
...
}

public Game<T extends GameTable, P extends Player>
{
...
   public T getTable();

   public List<P> getPlayers();
} 

public interface GameFactory<T extends GameTable, P extends Player, G extends Game>
{
   public G getGameInstance(T table, List<P> players)
} 

public interface GameTable<P extends Player, G extends Game, GF extends GameFactory>
{
...
   public G getCurrentGame();

   public List<P> getPlayers();
}
```

The nice thing about this is that for example a CheckersGame would then be declared as:

```
   public interface CheckersGame extends Game<CheckersTable, CheckersPlayer>
   {
     public CheckersTable getTable();

     public List<CheckersPlayer> getPlayers();
   }
```

So far so good.

Each `GameTable` in fact has a lot in common, and I opted to use the Template Pattern to put some common algorithm logic in an abstract implementation, and then the respective concrete class extending it would just 'fill in the blanks' with the game-specific stuff.

However, now I am getting all sorts of 'bounds' errors in my Generics stuff.

My `AbstractTable` is declared as follows:

```
public abstract class AbstractTable<P extends Player, G extends Game, GF extends GameFactory> implements GameTable<P,G,GF>
{      
  GF gameFactory; 

  ...
  public final void startGame()
  {
    //the following line does not work
    G newGame = gameFactory.getGameInstance(this, getPlayers());
  }

}
```

The line with the factory method for some reason does not work and returns `Game` not `G`.
So I tried to change the class declaration to also be more specific about the types of the `GameFactory` Generic type:

```
  public abstract class AbstractTable<P extends Player, G extends Game, GF extends GameFactory<? extends GameTable, P, G> 
        implements GameTable<P,G,GF>
```

But now I got a type mismatch between the type being passed (`AbstractTable<P,G,GF>`) and the expected type `? extends GameTable`.

So I tried to modify the factory as follows too:

```
public interface GameFactory<T extends GameTable<P, G, ? extends GameFactory>, P extends Player, G extends Game>
```

Which still didn't work out.

I don't know if this cyclic dependency between Generic types is at all possible, but it seems I got myself in a chicken-egg situation with nested generics.

Is there any way to have this properly done? Unfortunately I need both the concrete `GameTable` and `Game` types to know about each other, since one needs to refer to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed generics with non-generics and this tends to lead to confusion. In Game you have given it two generics parameter types, but in GameFactory it is treated as a non-generic. Try to make all your types consistently either generic or non-generic and it should work.

e.g.

```
public interface GameFactory<T extends GameTable, P extends Player, G extends Game<T,P>> {
    public G getGameInstance(T table, List<P> players)
}
```

or better to not specify the implementing class returned. After all its a factory which hides details like what concrete class it returns.

```
public interface GameFactory<T extends GameTable, P extends Player> {
    public Game<T,P> getGameInstance(T table, List<P> players)
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to have the Generic GameFactory interface extended by the more specific GameFactory, which will still be an interface. So I would prefer the former case. So, GameTable has been ungenerified in your example? And how would you declare the AbstractTable? Thanks.

Comment: @jbx, I see your problem. I think you are in danger of making it so generic it doesn't make sense.  Perhaps some YAGNI design is worth considering here. ;) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it

Comment: OK, what I did to circumvent this problem is that I removed the reference of GameFactory to the GameTable all together to avoid the cyclic generification. So GameFactory<P extends Player, G extends Game> and the method itself just takes public G getGameInstance(GameTable table, List<P> players).  In the actual concrete factory implementation I inserted an instanceof to have a real time check (OK its not compile time, but neat and localised), and its implementation specific, so whoever is implementing the specific factory can check if he wants to.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need this dependency GameTable <-> Game? Is not enough for GameTable to retrieve the game instance from gameFactory.getGameInstance() by using an enum indicating a type of table? Basically I will try to reduce the dependencies between interfaces/interfaces and classes/interfaces.

Comment: No, remember this is a framework that will not know about its implementing classes. They could potentially be in another JAR file or implemented by someone else. So having an enum is not an option. What I am trying to achieve here is the strong typing between associated concrete classes of Game, GameFactory, Player and GameTable

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your GameFactory returns "G extends Game", and you are trying to assign that to another "G extends Game" which is potentially not the same class (even though it actually is in your implementation).

One way to resolve that would be for GameFactory to return a "Game", rather than "something that extends Game".